# How to Trigger OnPropertyChanged in ViewModel on change of Property inside ObservableCollection<Object>?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I normally don't ask questions on StackOverflow but this problem is really doing my head in.

I have the need to fire a OnPropertyChanged-call for a property located in my ViewModel when a property inside ObservableCollection changes. Here is my set-up:

```
public sealed class ObjectExtended
{
    private decimal? _percentage;
    public decimal? Percentage
    {
        get { return _percentage; }
        set
        {
            if (_percentage == value) return;
            _percentage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Percentage");


TODO: //Need to fire OnPropertyChanged("TotalCost") on ViewModel
        }
    }
}


public class TheViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ObjectExtended> _objects;
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectExtended> Objects
    {
        get { return _objects; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_objects, value)) return;
            _objects = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Objects");
        }
    }

    public decimal? TotalCost
    {
        get
        {
            var result = Objects.Where(x => x.status == SelectedObject.status).Select(x => x.costValue).Sum();
            return Math.Truncate(result * 100) / 100;
        }
    }
}
```

So when the Percentage is edited, I want to trigger an update of the value of TotalCost in the view. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty simple way to do it is to just hook into the property changed events of the list items and raise your own property changed whenever the property you are watching for changes.

After your observable collection is created

```
Objects.CollectionChanged += Objects_CollectionChanged;
```

Then

```
void Objects_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems.Cast<System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged>())
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems.Cast<System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged>())
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
                }
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "Percentage")
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("TotalCost");
        }
    }
```

You will also need to handle the reset (clear) and replace cases to be safe.

Also if your observable collection has any items in it before attaching the collection changed handler then you will have to loop through and hook into them as well.

Comment: One change I would suggest, use a [`PropertyChagnedEventManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to give you weak events between the elements and your class. That way the class could potentially get garbage collected even if one of the elements in the collection still was rooted.

Comment: Thanks bonyjoe, your suggested solution works like a charm! Also thanks to Scott for the additional information. Cheers guys!